# How to validate a date field date using Rich Harrison's validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the `validate.js` library of Rich Harrison:

http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

I have a doubt, I need to validate a date field format, the format would be DD/MM/YYYY

This is the JS code:

```
name: 'date-birth',
display: 'Date of Birth',
rules: 'required|max_length[10]'
```

I have seen, the next functions: `greater_than_date`, `less_than_date`, `greater_than_or_equal_date` and `less_than_or_equal_date`

How can I do it?

Comment: Where have you seen `greater_than_date`, etc?  These rules are not included with this plugin.

Comment: In http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/, download the file validate.js, in this file, there are the  greater_than_date function

Comment: But they're not in the documentation, so maybe these are not fully working.  Otherwise, if the rule exists, then how are you stuck?

Comment: this is how rare, there are not documentation, i only want to validate a date field with this plugin, maybe I should use another plugin.